# How to integrate Spring with jPMN?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, jbpm

I have project on Spring(mvc,jpa,security,jms,transaction on Bitronix)

How to integrate spring with jBPMN?

How to add or remove objects from the database in jbpm?

Are there any examples of integration? There are quite a few of them on the Internet and they are quite simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing kie-server-spring-boot-starter: https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/kie-spring-boot/kie-spring-boot-starters/kie-server-spring-boot-starter-jbpm

Or configure your own starter project with on https://start.jbpm.org